# What's a good element to pair with the element of darkness for my magic system?

Tags: magic

Edit: I've been told my question is a little too opinion based. I'll edit/clarify the question to the best of my limited intelligence and capability, but if its still too opinion based I won't fight it being closed. Thank you to everyone who contributed/may contribute and I apologize for the inconvenience.

My magic system involves groupings of elements called domains which have a unique property not specific to either element in said domain. A user of a domain can not only manipulate their elemental affinities but conjure said element as well. This is done using the base magical energy in my system called "Phantasia".

As the title implies I'm looking for a element to be paired with darkness. So far I've been using "void" as the element paired with it. It being negation of other elements or properties. But I've started to dislike it due to the negation aspect encroaching on the unique property of the domain, that being restriction. The restriction property allows someone to limit themselves by imposing restrictive rules on their abilities. While doing so will hamper them in some way, the greater the restriction the greater the power is gained in return. They can also restrict the abilities of others. I felt the negation aspect of the void element was too similar to the unique property not meant to be specific to either element, in this case restriction.

With this in mind what's a good element to pair with darkness that fits the unique property I've established?

Also just so people don't suggest elements or powers I've already put in other domains, the elements I already have and their unique properties are:

Fire and poison. Unique property: Infliction. The ability to inflict lasting damage by chipping away and disintegrating something/someone or status effects often in the form of poisons or burns.

Fauna and flora. Unique property: Absorption. The ability of a person to absorb enemy Phantasia powers and constructs into their own Phantasia.

Earth and metal. Unique property: Creation. The ability to create items that can only be stable if shared.

Water and ice. Unique property: Enervation. The ability to slow and weaken the bonds of Phantasia from their enemies, halting their functions.

Light and sound. Unique property: Specialization. The ability to share Phantasia with others to "specialize" in certain benefits. Often in the form of support skills or healing. Think buffing stats in a video game.

Wind and electricity. Unique property: Channeling. The ability to channel incredible amounts or hostile forces of Phantasia with little to no harm. Often used in the form of counter attacks.

Space and time. Unique property: Distortion. The ability to create distortions in the Phantasia from their enemies or around them and then manipulate said distorted Phantasia to their whim. Usually in the form of creating unique rules or properties to the Phantasia they distort.

The abilities involving mind reading, mind manipulation, dream manipulation, and illusions are base powers in the magic system not specific to any domain.

As can be seen with the grouping of fire and poison together, I'm don't need the element suggestions to match perfectly in substance with darkness. Just the overall theme of the domain it's in and it's unique property. In the case of fire and poison it's the ability to inflict lasting damage or status effects. While the domain darkness is in is a more rogue like one. Whose roles are primarily stealth via restricting/limiting their own presence as well as trapping/capture by restricting the powers of others.

I also don't really need the element to counter or be opposite to the domain of light and sound. Since I have it set up that any element can be sufficient against any other in a battle provided the willpower and other factors.

A best answer should include an element type power not expressed in the above list of elements already present in the system or in their unique properties.

Comment: Can you extend on what Space and Time is able to do?

Comment: While suggestions to mechanics can be made in an answer to a question, questions that deliberately ask for a suggestion are usually deemed opinion-based. One rule of thumb to help determining if your question is opinion based is to ask if you can actually establish criteria to a best answer. Since you state darkness is essentially about remaining hidden and quiet, how would you choose between, say, an answer suggesting "plasma" (it's bright and energetic) and another suggesting "pressure waves" (cause abrupt movement, destruction an loud noises) if both were equally convincing?

Comment: @ProjectApex Sorry I'm not sure I understand. I thought I gave criteria by listing what powers I already have as well as the theme of what I'm looking for. As for your examples I would say that plasma is a little too similar to fire and/or electricity via lightning. And for pressure waves also being too similar to sound or it could even be argued as being similar with space as well. so neither fit the criteria in the first place. Again sorry for not understanding or if I did something wrong. I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed.

Comment: I might not have been the clearest either. Listing the powers does limit the amount of suggestions that can be made, but doesn't help as much to make the question seem less opinion based. Apart from examples (because mine were not the best), how would you determine a best answer between 2 choices if both seemed equally valid? Editing your question to add in something like "a best answer should include [traits you desire]" is a great way to show the question can select a best answer via something other than. "This sounds the coolest" or something similar, preventing it from being closed down.

Comment: Hope I was able to be more clear this time. Stating in a clearer way what you want to see in a "best answer" might be what it takes to cause the close votes casted on your question to be removed. You didn't do anything wrong, it's just that 4 people saw your question as opinion based, and I'm trying to help you fix that. This entry on the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) can hopefully help you better than me.

Comment: This post will be "opinion-based" as long as this is your core question: "what's a good element to pair with darkness that fits the unique property I've established?"

Comment: I can't detect a pattern to the examples you've posted, so I don't think there's enough information here to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thematically, void pairs very well with darkness.  Instead of worrying about whether void is right or wrong, you should be looking at why void is not standing on its own.

Basically your problem boils down to this:

[image]

You just need to answer what it is that Void does in addition to restriction.

When I look at some of your other pairings, it seems like most of them include one element representing the benign side of the domain (wind, water, earth, etc) and then thier counterparts are like thier more destructive cousins (electricity, ice, metal).  So if you follow this logic, then Void should be the destructive partner to Darkness.  So while darkness hides things from you, Void makes them stop existing all together. For example, while a Darkness spell may hide you from being seen, a void spell might make your opponent's spear suddenly disappear.  Both restrict the enemy's ability to harm you, but in very different ways.

This way Void can stand on its own as a thing, but also have the shared aspect of restriction with darkness

Answer (score 5):

Why not "silence", since light is already occupied with sound?

Or, if you want it to have something distinct (I noticed you aren't doing the "opposites" thing with fire and ice, so there's no reason to do it with darkness, either, I guess), maybe you could do "insects", with an eye toward nightcrawlers.

Or, if you don't want to couple something nonliving with something living (I noticed Fauna and Flora are together), maybe "radiation", because it passes most easily through the dark void of space.

Or, if you want a thicker darkness, then maybe "color", because darkness absorbs all the colors.

Some others, maybe... "emotion", "depth", "gravity", "mass", or "force".

Honestly, I don't think void needs to be thought of as a negation of other elements, though. Consider Homestuck's use of void, where the "rogue of void" would "steal nonexistence from a thing", so whereas the thing might previously had "nonexistence" as a property (ignoring the philosophical problems with that), the thing would lose that property and pop into existence, and the character used it to create different mundane objects. Or, if you want to employ a more traditional perspective on the void, a void person could manipulate black holes and stuff; creating a vacuum anywhere -- maybe even a vacuum which demands fulfillment by a specific element and attracts magic of another sort towards it in particular.

Idk, just brainstorming. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

**Silence** comes first to mind. Just like darkness is the absence of light, silence is the absence of sound. And It fits well with the whole stealth aspect of this domain: You can make yourself unheard while sneaking about, or silence an enemy shouting alarm.

It can also be used offensively, especially when coupled with darkness. You deprive the enemy of their ability to sense the environment well, and they can also not coordinate with each other. Easy prey for a rogue.

It can also be used with the restriction property of the domain. Restrict your own hearing, but gain a lot of power, or improved sight in return.

Answer (score 1):

The trick seems to be that you want something to tie into the theme of restriction without necessarily overpowering the theme or making the first element useless.  Given your propensity to make it a more rogue-like domain, and to add some interesting potential to it, I propose your alternate element is **Stillness**

**Stillness** represents restriction by prevention of movement.  It is named for the most common thought/use of stopping the body from moving.  However, sound is moving air -- still the air and you still the sound in theory.  A heart and lungs have to move to function, if you still them then death follows swiftly.  If Phantasia flows in any way, it can theoretically be stilled, a terrifying prospect to those that rely on such powers.

Stillness seeks not to restrict things by hiding or obscuring things as Darkness might be more apt to so.  It works in more overt ways, restricting action by more direct effects, even if not readily visible.

This is not to say that it is always an offensive domain.  Stilling nerves to calm down when dealing with a stressful situation can be useful in a variety of situations to name likely a common thing people would strive for.

The only problem I can really see is that this doesn't really have much in the flashy moves department.  Stilled air to act as barriers is possible, but there isn't the same flashy effects that other disciplines might have.  But for a more rogue-like domain that might be the feature and not the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Secret or dreams:

maybe based around the mind reading or some other psic power.  It would fit with the more positive aspects of darkness.